# How to logged in dashboard with different credential while use multi authentication in laravel 8?

Tags: php, authentication, eloquent, laravel-8

Config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'webstudent' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'students',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'students' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
    ],
],
```

LoginController.php

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
    {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }
    else if(Auth::guard('webstudent')->attempt(['email_id' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
    {
        return redirect()->route('student.dashboard');
    }
    return redirect()->route('login')->with(['error'=>'Login details are not valid']);
}
```

In the above code I have two table in my database i.e. `User` and `Student`. In case of `guard = web` I simply use `email and password` to login which is successfully working but in case of `guard = webstudent` I want to log in with `email_id and mobile_no as password` it shows `Login details are not valid`.

I am also trying to override `mobile_no` with `password` with help to add function in `Student` model. Code as mention below:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->mobile_no;
}
```

But still it work for `guard = web` and not working in `student` case. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: First of all, this is wrong: `else if(Auth::guard('webstudent')`, it should be `elseif). Second: try to use some debugging in that `attempt` function

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand why you want to use mobile_no as password. It’s not secure. However, if you persist to use it, you can consider this solution:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
    {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }
    else if($student = Student::where(['email_id' => $request->email, 'mobile_no' => $request->password])->first())
    {
         Auth::guard('webstudent')->login($student);
         return redirect()->route('student.dashboard');
    }
    return redirect()->route('login')->with(['error'=>'Login details are not valid']);
}
```